# Differentiate between 0 and 0.0 in c as breaking condition of a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, precision, break

I am trying to break my while loop.
My program should break the loop if the character '0' is inserted.
However, if the character '0.0' is inserted, the program should not break the loop and continue working. I have already tried different solutions (getchar, gets) but without success.
Any ideas ?

```
while(1)
{
    double x[1000];
    scanf("%lf", &x[i]);

    if(x[i]=0 && x[i]!=0.0)
        break;

    i++;
}
```

Comment: You are talking about `char`, and using `double`? BTW, `0.0` is not a single `char`.

Comment: I made an error using the word "character".

Comment: `x[i]` is a double. You simply cannot differentiate between `0` and `0.0`. They are the same.

Comment: And do not compare floating point values with `==`...

Comment: @Macmade Comparing to `0` is fine. That can be represented exactly.

Comment: Since all integer values are also real values, you would perhaps do better to use a non-numeric character as the terminating condition and check the return value of scanf() to terminate - scanf() returns the number converted fields, so will return 0 in this case if the input is not a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x[i]=0 && x[i]!=0.0)
```

In `x[i]=0` you are assigning (not comparing)

In order to differentiate between `0` and `0.0` you need to compare a string (instead of a `double`)

```
scanf("%s", str);
if (str[0] == '0' && strchr(str, '.') == NULL) {
    /* 0 */
}
```

Then, you can convert to `double`

```
x[i] = strtod(str, NULL);
```

Comment: I didn't DV. But it was quite clear from the description that OP wanted to treat `0` as an exit condition and treat `0.0` as a valid input.

Answer (score 2):

`x[i]` is of type double and `0` gets converted into a double when comparing. So whether you use `0.0` or `0`, it makes no difference. In IEEE-754, `0` is represented as all bits 0. So it would make no difference in the comparison. You can't differentiate `0` from `0.0`. I really don't understand why you have such a loop condition which makes you treat them distinctly.

Having said that, you could use use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to read as a string and compare it with `0`. If not, convert it to `double` using [`strtod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html).

```
while(1)
{
    double x[1000];
    char buf[256];
    char *p;

    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);    
    p = strchr(buf, '\n');
    if(p) *p = 0;  // Remove the trailing newline, if present
    if (strcmp(buf, "0") == 0) break;

    x[i] = strtod(buf, 0);   

    i++;
}
```

Left out the error checking for brevity. In real code, you should check for the failures `fgets()` and `strtod()`.

Comment: This requires each value to be on a newline with no trailing characters whereas the original would have also accepted space separated data in a single line.

Comment: Notable difference, I agree. But I try to avoid `scanf()` as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Text converted to a `double()` does not retain its original textual form.

Read the test as a string and test for the end condition

```
#define N 1000
#define BUFN 80
double x[N];
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  char buf[BUFN];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break;

  // Scan for end pattern: (optional white-space) 0 (optional white-space)
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(" 0 %n", &n);  // n is set when pattern is matched
  if (n > 0) break;

  // error checking omitted for brevity
  double x[i] = strtod(buf, 0);
}
```